# Обновление Label

Tags: c#, winforms

на форме1 нажимаю кнопку, она запускает таймер, после истечения времени запускается форма2 и поистечению времени уже там форма2 закрывается и на форме1 время должно восстановится, ну чтобы отображало в label, все более менее работает но не знаю куда пихнуть label для повторного отображения

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadSettings();
        }

        Properties.Settings setts = new Properties.Settings();
        public Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        public static int minInterval;
        public static int minRelax;
        public static int sec;

        void LoadSettings()
        {
            Properties.Settings setts = new Properties.Settings();

            f3.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = setts.TimeInterval;
            f3.comboBox2.SelectedIndex = setts.TimeRelax;
        }

        void SaveSettings()
        {
            Properties.Settings setts = new Properties.Settings();

            setts.TimeInterval = f3.comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
            setts.TimeRelax = f3.comboBox2.SelectedIndex;
            setts.Save();
        }

        public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sec = sec - 1;
            if (sec == -1)
            {
                minInterval = minInterval - 1;
                sec = 59;
            }
            if (minInterval == 0 && sec == 0)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                Console.Beep(659, 100);
                Form1_Load(sender, e);
                f2.Show(); //вот мы открываем форму2
            }
            label2.Text = minInterval.ToString() + ":" + sec.ToString();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadSettings();
            if (f3.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                Form1.minInterval = 5;
            }
            if (f3.comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                Form1.minRelax = 1;
            }
        }

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (timer1.Enabled)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = false;
                buttonStart.Text = "Старт";
                buttonRestart.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                buttonStart.Text = "Стоп";
                buttonRestart.Enabled = false;
            }

        }

        private void buttonRestart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            Form1_Load(sender, e);
            label2.Text = minInterval.ToString() + ":" + sec.ToString();
        }


**ФОРМА2**
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        int sec;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Beep(659, 100);
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            //Form1 f1 = new Form1(); //это не работает (не понимаю)
            //f1.timer1.Enabled = true; //это не работает (не понимаю)
            this.Close();
            //и вот тут после закрытия формы2 должен перейти к таймеру формы1, чтобы он опять работал.
```

form1.timer1_Tick(sender, e); //это типа хочу перейти так
            }

```
    }
```

Comment: А что Label должен отображать?

Comment: время, опять должно сброситься и идти заного, все работает по времени но он повторно не отображает(

Comment: ты хочешь чтобы было отдельное окно с отсчетом времени или чтобы имелся label на формах?

Comment: На форме1 есть label где показывает время, как время  устанавливается в 0, открывается форма2 и после того как мы закрываем форму2, у нас на форме1 вновь должно время идти в label. Дело в том что все идет (время считает), но в label уже повторно не кажет.

Comment: Добавь в вопрос код программы, или код функционала который относится к этому вопросу. Это поможет ответить на вопрос

Comment: добавил код в шапку

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Form2 уберите создание новых экземпляров Form1.

```
    public void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sec = sec - 1;
        if (sec == -1)
        {
            minInterval = minInterval - 1;
            sec = 59;
        }
        if (minInterval == 0 && sec == 0)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            Console.Beep(659, 100);
            Form1_Load(sender, e);
            f2.ShowDialog();
            LoadSettings();
            SetTimeIfZero();
            timer1.Enabled=f2.timerSet;
            f2.Dispose();
        }
        label2.Text = minInterval.ToString() + ":" + sec.ToString();
    }

    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSettings();
        SetTimeIfZero();
    }

    private void SetTimeIfZero()
    {
        if (f3.comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            Form1.minInterval = 5;
        if (f3.comboBox2.SelectedIndex == 0)
            Form1.minRelax = 1;
    }
```

В Form 2 добавьте переменную public bool timerSet=false; и в button1_Click (Form2) добавьте timerSet=true;

Comment: Не это совсем не то, это я получается устанавливаю минуты по окончанию, но это я делаю через Form1_Load(sender, e); , а мне нужно чтобы label как-то обновился, да он ставит эту 5 в минуты, но я не вижу процесса что он отсчитывает вот в чем проблема. Мне нужно чтобы он опять считал (отображал в label), так-то он считает но label не обновляется после открытия form2

Comment: Изменил код, надо было снова активировать таймер

Comment: Да, начало работать че-то, но после закрытия формы2 секунды отнимает уже по 2, еще раз после открытия формы2 и ее закрытия уже отнимает по 3 и так далее и посе 2ого раза уже накладывается друг на друга

Comment: Я щас в форме2 убрал Form1 f1 = new Form1();            f1.timer1.Enabled = true; и вроде стало работать как я хотел, но почему мой код не правильный? таймер формы же должен активироваться после закрытия формы2, как я написал, а мы его теперь активируем в форме1, после отображения формы2. Вот это я не особо понимаю....

Comment: У тебя генерировался новый экземпляр формы, а переменная             `Form1.minInterval` статическая и её меняло сразу две формы. Статические переменные одни и те же для разных экземпляров и на них влияло два или более экземпляра (если несколько раз ты их использовал) т.е. timerTick выполнялся на нескольких экземплярах и отнимал значение `minInterval`

Comment: так я же запускал таймер формы1 после закрытия формы2     Form1 f1 = new Form1(); f1.timer1.Enabled = true; а щас мы его сюда добавили f2.ShowDialog(); timer1.Enabled = true; вот тут почему так? Твой пример правильный, но скажи почему мой-то не правильный, хотя он также работал но label тока не работал

Comment: В тике Form1 ты не закрывал форму, `f2.ShowDialog();` останавливает работы Form1 до тех пор пока не закроется Form2. В Form2 ты создавал новый экземпляр f1. После закрытия Form2 включался таймер и тик выполнялся на двух экземплярах. А потом 3 экземпляра 4,5,... и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо, щас я понял, что тут был важен f2.ShowDialog(), а вот еще 1 вопрос, если я поставлю f2.Show() , тогда как быть?

Comment: Если сделаешь `f2.Show()` то после открытия Form2 сразу выполнится код после него. Если тебе требуется возвращать информацию с Form2 в Form1, то сделай возвращаемые функции после f2.ShowDialog() считывай.

Comment: Можно код пожалуйста? Если я поставлю f2.Show(); я вот добавляю чтобы он возвратил настройки Form1_Load(sender, e); , а форме2 как сделать чтобы после закрытия работа возобновилась? timer этот с label чтобы работал          (это в форме2, после нажатии кнопки закрываем окно и должно заного запустить таймер в форме1)  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.minRelax = 0;
            sec = 0;
            Console.Beep(659, 100);
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            this.Close();
        }

Comment: @user287413 изменил ответ, если я правильно понял то решение там

Comment: Не, вот как вы писили f2.ShowDialog();
                Form1_Load(sender, e);
                timer1.Enabled = true; тока теперь должно быть f2.Show(); и в форме2 после нажатия кнопки мы закрываем форму2 и переходим как бы к таймеру этому, из формы1 (showdialog не используем), щас обновлю код, чтобы было понятнее.

Comment: Если будет стоять f2.Show(); появится проблема с обнаружением закрытия формы, вам же требуется после закрытия Form2 через кнопку активировать таймер так?

Comment: да мы открываем по окончанию таймера формы1 форму2 и там по кнопке форма2 закрывается и опять снова вы переходим к таймеру формы1. я обновил код в шапке.

Comment: Исправил код, надеюсь это точно то что вы ищете

Comment: Не особо понял, но спасибо за тот ответ с кодом showdialog.

Comment: советую прочитать про ООП, узнаете много интересного и полезного)

Comment: Лучше конечно смотреть прям примеры нормальные (много всяких ситуаций), а то кажут легкотню, которую сто раз изъездили. Я раньше писал плагины для майнкрафта на java ну и там глядел чужие коды, там прога была специальная можно глядеть коды, и так я учился смотря примеры чужих плагинов, смотрел что к чему)